# Keyboard Layout change inside a script

Tags: bash, scripts, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've built a live cd which has no x11 on it. I like to use only the Console. But the keyboard layout is wrong.

Since I'm using GITLAB CI and a docker Runner to build the CD I must change it via a script.

I tried to change my build so that the file with the config is automatically written onto the cd as I read on several posts here.

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/default/keyboard
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="ch"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
EOF
```

Sadly my keyboard layout is still wrong, even though i installed the **console-data** package. Any ideas how I could get it right.

the command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data
```

isn't really an option, because it's interactive

Comment: Running `loadkeys ch` (as root) after the boot is a simple solution, how about that?

Comment: @dessert thanks, but i think there must be a better way, because the login prompt will not be in swiss german.